# How to append multiple comma separated values to same key

Tags: java

I have a APIkey like this:

```
String mainUrl = "http://smshorizon.co.in/api/sendsms.php?";"&mobile= MOBILE_NUMBER1, MOBILE_NUMBER2, MOBILE_NUMBER3";
```

I want to add multiple mobile numbers as comma separated values to the key(`"&mobile="`). I tried to use hasp map with list but the problem is it adds the values as array because it is a collection.

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap();       
List<String> list = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    list.add(numbers[i]);
    hm.put("&mobile=", list);
}
System.out.println("HashMap: " + hm.get("&mobile="));
System.out.println("message: " + message);

//prints HashMap: [996****730, 97052***86, 984****956]
```

How do I add it as comma separated values like:

```
String mainUrl = "http://smshorizon.co.in/api/sendsms.php?";"&mobile= MOBILE_NUMBER1, MOBILE_NUMBER2, MOBILE_NUMBER3";
```

Comment: In Hashmap you are storing list as a value for the key "&mobile=". Rather than that, you just make a string and append mobile number with it seperated by comma.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a `StringBuilder` and iterate over your numbers, appending the number itself and a comma after. Then you'd erase the last character (the trailing comma) and put the `String` you built as your value.

Comment: From Apache Commons library: String str = StringUtils.join(list, ',');hm.put("&mobile=", str);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8, it can be done like this:

```
String[] numbers = {"MOBILE_NUMBER1", "MOBILE_NUMBER2", "MOBILE_NUMBER3"};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(numbers).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

**Output:**

```
MOBILE_NUMBER1,MOBILE_NUMBER2,MOBILE_NUMBER3
```

With previous versions of Java use a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        buffer.append(',');
    }
    buffer.append(numbers[i]);
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

**Output:**

```
MOBILE_NUMBER1,MOBILE_NUMBER2,MOBILE_NUMBER3
```

Comment: Although all the answers work. I am accepting it as answer for java 8 feature

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use a StringBuilder and iterate over your numbers, appending the number itself and a comma after. Then you'd erase the last character (the trailing comma) and put the String you built as your value.

**Example**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// assuming the "numbers" variable is a String array or collection
for (String number: numbers) {
    sb.append(number).append(",");
}
// removing trailing ","
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1)
hm.put("&mobile=", sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap();       
String mobileNumbers;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers + "," + numbers[i];

}
mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers.subString(1); //To remove first comma.
hm.put("&mobile=", mobileNumbers);

System.out.println("HashMap: " + hm.get("&mobile="));
System.out.println("message: " + message);

//prints HashMap: 99****8730, 97******86, 98******56
```